# how to reflect Supplier name automatically in "SupplierNameTextBox"

Tags: c#

how to reflect Supplier name automatically  in "SupplierNameTextBox" by entering supplier id in "IDTextBox"

i have SQL table "SupplierMaster" with two column "SupplierID" and "SupplierName"
I am using c# coding for my application

Comment: just call sql query on textchanged event of IDTextBox to get Supplier Name from table for id  and set this value to SupplierNameTextBox text